# JQuery changes in CSS do not stay

Tags: jquery, css

I use JQuery to hide some parts of my page and show others (the current sub-page, while hiding all others). However when i click on the buttons the change applies for only 1 second and after that the styling resets to the default...

This is part of the code, for example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#NavMenu a").on('click', function() {

   var chosen = $(this).attr("id");

   $(".SubPage").css('display', 'none');
   $(".SubPage, #" + chosen).css('display', 'block');

 });
});
```

SubPage = class used in all sub-articles on the page;
NavMenu = id of the main menu used to select parts of the page;
Every sub-page has its own id that the variable "chosen" holds.

*** If I change the attributes to others (for test purposes), like 'font-size' being changed and not 'display', for instance, they still blink for a second and switch back to what they used to be.

Comment: This sounds like it's coming from elsewhere in your code.  Without a more detailed example, all we can do is guess.  Have you tried reproducing this in something like jsfiddle?

Comment: I copy-pasted it there but when I try to click on a link in the menu it blinks again and then says: "{"error": "Please use POST request"}". Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using some plugin to style the menu? You need to provide more info's.

Comment: No. In fact, I am new to website dev and use only basic stuff.

Comment: Please post the jsfiddle link here

Comment: Also feel free to use the `.hide()` method instead of `.css('display', 'none')` it'll save you a few characters :) (and `.show()` will show it again)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/d68W5/

However it doesn't seem to display things as it does on my PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've updated [your JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d68W5/3/) to something that works.

I cut a lot out, because you included more than you needed to.

One of your selectors was wrong:

```
 $(".SubPage, #" + chosen).css('display', 'block');
```

needed to be:

```
 $(".SubPage#" + chosen).css('display', 'block');
```

Also note, you can use the simple [`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) and [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) methods:

```
 $("#NavMenu a").on('click', function() {
    var chosen = $(this).attr("id");
   $(".SubPage").hide();
   $(".SubPage#" + chosen).show();
  });
```

Comment: Thanks! You helped a lot! :) Do you know what was causing this? However, I wonder - if i remove the "#" hash from the <a href> tags on the menu, it stops working. On the other hand - if it stays, when the page is reloaded it appends that hashtag to the address, which bugs me. It looks bad. I have seen sites that are not like that. The href is something like: href="javascript:someFunctionThatDoesThatSwitching()", but I don't understand that.

Comment: href="javascript:void(0)" seems to do the trick, but I am open to other suggestions as well (that one seems a little hacky). Also I am most curious about what was causing the initial error.

Comment: I had to change the href to make it work, yes. And `#` is pretty standard, if you don't like it then use a hack. Most people seem to be okay with it :)